# Yes and No keys/values using parse_ini_file

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a simple translation class but I'm stuck on a tricky problem.

Here's the method that's doing the translation:

```
public function translate($textToTranslate)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($textToTranslate, $this->languageArray) || $this->languageArray[$textToTranslate] == null)
        {
            return $textToTranslate;
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->languageArray[$textToTranslate];
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I pass **Yes** or **No** to be translated. I believe they're treated as true/false and it doesn't display what is supposed to.  So my question is can I use Yes and No in this scenario and if yes - how?

I was just using `parse_ini_file()` and this is the place where the problem comes from. Because as stated in the documentation, keys like yes, no and few other can't be used.

Comment: If you're passing 'Yes' and 'No' then there shouldn't be any reason for them to be evaluated as booleans.  What debugging have you tried?

Comment: Thanks! This is correct. I was just using parse_ini_file() and this is the place where the problem comes from. Because as stated in the documentation, keys like yes, no and few other can't be used.

Comment: You are correct, parsing the ini will convert values of yes to 1 and no to empty string. They can't be used as a key at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual for `parse_ini_file()`:

> Note: There are reserved words which must not be used as keys for ini
>   files. These include: null, yes, no, true, false, on, off, none.
>   Values null, off, no and false result in "". Values on, yes and true
>   result in "1". Characters ?{}|&~!()^" must not be used anywhere in the
>   key and have a special meaning in the value.

If you had `error_reporting` on you would see:

> Warning: syntax error, unexpected BOOL_FALSE in Unknown
>
> Warning: syntax error, unexpected BOOL_TRUE in Unknown

So there are two options I can think of:

1. Use an array which will accept the reserved words as a key:

   `word[no] = "nein"`

Then you would have to rework your ini file and your application for the `word` array.

2. Use a significant character and then `trim()` it in the function:

   `*no = "nein"`

Then in the function:

```
$textToTranslate = trim($textToTranslate, '*');
```

Comment: Yeah, I already did it with adding additional symbol and trimming it after.
Probably not the best solution(writing new function to parse the .ini file?) I guess but it works :)